# Custom Role membership provider

Tags: asp.net-membership

We are trying to implement Custom Role membership provider for our web app. For authorization we want to check for one more field like  Facilityid  for the logged on user along with role he has. eg. my User1 having Role1 with Facility1 can access some option and same user role for Facility2 have different option. So is there a way we can extend the existing role/profile provider to authorize user with this additional field along with role assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complicated you expect this to be you might want to just have Facility1 and Facility2 be roles, even though they may share a lot of the same aspects.  In this manner, you should not need to extend the membership provider.

Comment: +1 unless requirements absolutely require a customized stack, sweet talking the built in stack is generally the best route.

Answer (score 0):

There can be n facilities so having those many roles does not look fesiable. If we can find a way by which we can pass the Facilityid from the application to this security module roleprovider and fetch appropriate role for user only for that facility.